# How to write function values to excel

Tags: python, loops, selenium, web-scraping, openpyxl

I have made a webscraper that prints the price, Seller name and barcode of a product.

However, I can't figure out how to write the given values to excel.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import openpyxl
import time
import os  

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
cell = sheet['A1']
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop\\Webscraper\\chromedriver.exe')


#---------------------Base Bones----------------------------------------------
def start_browser():
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/shopping?hl=en');
    time.sleep(1)

def sku_selector(barcode):
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="lst-ib"]')
    search_box.send_keys(barcode)
    search_box.submit()

def get_url():
    print(driver.current_url)

def repeat():
    driver.get('https://www.google.com/shopping?hl=en')

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------



#----------------------Main Scraper---------------------------------------------


def scraper():

    #Step 1: Selects the first product after search
    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Looking for product....')
        product_select = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('#rso > div.sh-sr__shop-result-group.BXIkFb > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.ZGFjDb > div > div.eIuuYe > a')
        product_select.click()
        print('Product found! Clicking it')

    #Step 2: clicks on "Compare Prices" to open Google sopping product page 

        time.sleep(2)
        print('Trying to open product page...')
        compare_shops = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('#rso > div > div > div.pspo-popout.pspo-lpop > div > div > div > div.pspo-content > div.pspo-fade > div._-mc > div._-eo > div > a > div')
        compare_shops.click()
        print('Success! Opening the product')

    except:
     #Step 1: Selects the first pruduct after search------ needs more work
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Looking for product again')

        product_close = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('#rso > div.sh-sr__shop-result-group.BXIkFb > div.sh-pr__product-results > div.pspo-popout.pspo-lpop > div > div > div > a')
        product_close.click()
        print('closing Product')

        time.sleep(2)
        product_select_2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('#rso > div:nth-child(2) > div.sh-pr__product-results > div.sh-dlr__list-result > div > div.ZGFjDb > div > div.eIuuYe > a')
        product_select_2.click()
        print('Product found! Clicking it')

    #Step 2.1: clicks on "Compare Prices" to open Google sopping product page 
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Trying to open product page...')
        compare_shops_2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('#rso > div:nth-child(2) > div.sh-pr__product-results > div.pspo-popout.pspo-lpop > div > div > div > div.pspo-content > div.pspo-fade > div._-mc > div._-eo > div > a')
        compare_shops_2.click()
        print('Success! Opening the product, using method 2')

    try:
        #Step 3: clicks on "Base Price" to sort via cheapest price
        print('Finding the lowest price')
        time.sleep(2)
        base_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('#os-price-col-txt')
        base_price.click()

        #Step 4: gets the first price and prints text
        time.sleep(2)
        get_price = driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="os-sellers-table"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]/span').text
        print(get_price)

        #Step 5: gets first seller name and prints text
        seller = driver.find_element_by_xpath ('//*[@id="os-sellers-table"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/span/a').text
        print(seller)

    except:
        time.sleep(3)
        print('Could not find lowest price. Using data in the top right corner')
        #Step 4.1: Gets the price from the top right
        topright_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('#bb-os-list > li:nth-child(1) > div.bb-price').text
        print(topright_price)
        #Step 5.1: Gets the seller name from the top right
        topright_seller = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('#bb-os-list > li:nth-child(1) > div.bb-seller').text
        print(topright_seller)

    #Step 5: Gets GTIN number and prints text
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Trying to get GTIN')
        gtin = driver.find_element_by_css_selector ('#specs > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > span.gaBVed').text
        print('Barcode:')
        print(gtin)
    except:
        print('Unable to find GTIN')

    #Step 6: Gets Url and prints
    time.sleep(1)
    print('URL:')
    print(driver.current_url)





#Starting Script------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



start_browser()

for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):   


    try:
        sku_selector(sheet['A' + str(row)].value)
        print('Looking for SKU ' + sheet['A' + str(row)].value) 

        scraper()
        repeat()

        print('Success! Using next SKU')




    except:
        repeat()
        get_url()
        print('-------------------------------------------------')
        print('|     Criticall Error! Trying next sku          |')
        print('-------------------------------------------------')



print('Done! All skus have been scraped')
```

If anyone has an idea how I should include writing to excel within this code, please let me know.

Comment: Why not use csv format, excel supports it.

Comment: Edwin is right, just output to csv and open in excel. You can also do a whole bunch of fun stuff with creating excel workbook and sheets etc but it's more work.

Comment: CSV is never as simple as people make out. For example, you need to know the encoding, the separator, how fields are quoted and handle all type conversions yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. For now, I went with the CSV format which works fairly well for my needs at the moment. Once I have got the scraper fully  set up I will try to directly write it to a CSV/XLSX file :)

Answer (score -1):

to save your results in csv file

```
with open('results.csv', "a", newline='') as fp:
    wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect='excel')
    wr.writerow([SKU1-14,60$,Amazon])
```

don't forget to return list of your results under scraper() function

```
scraper():
     ...
     results =[gtin,price,seller ...]
     return results
```